# no server suitable for synchronization found For NTP Service

Tags: synchronization, ntp, ntpd

I had to build `ntp` packages from the source and install all of them on some hosts. After the installation, `ntpdate 1.us.pool.ntp.org` works for the synchronization. However, when I tried to do `ntpdate <ip_add_of_another_host>` it shows me the following error

> 21 Jul 18:57:53 ntpdate[18287]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Even more weirdly, sometimes `ntpdate <ip_addr_of_another_host>` works after I try the `ntpdate 1.us.pool.ntp.org`

My configuration file of the ntp server:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift


# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.
server 127.1.1.0 # local clock
fudge 127.1.1.0 stratum 10
# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::
```

I also tried the default configuration when I did `apt-get install ntp`, but it does not work as well.

Answer (score 15):

You could try `ntpdate -buv 1.us.pool.ntp.org`

> **-b** is for when your machine is out of sync for more than 1000s
>
> **-u** makes ntpdate use unprivileged ports
>
> **-v** is for verbosity.

The respons on my system changes from the same error:

> no server suitable for synchronization found

into:

> 19 Dec 21:36:46 ntpdate[18781]: ntpdate 4.2.7p465@1.2483-o Sun Sep  7 08:14:50 UTC 2014 (1)
>
> 19 Dec 21:36:45 ntpdate[18781]: step time server 194.109.22.18 offset -6.540448 sec

Answer (score 0):

When the server you try to fetch the time from has no connection to an upstream NTP server, then it is not suitable for synchronisation.

Answer (score -1):

Even we were facing this issue.... But we managed to resolve it by hitting this command:

```
ssh localhost "sudo apt-get install ntp ntpdate ; sudo service ntp stop; sudo ntpdate 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org; sudo service ntp start"
```

For this you need to install **openssh-server**

Also, remove ntp and ntpdate **(sudo apt-get remove --purge ntp ntpdate)** before firing the above "ssh" command.

Comment: What is that for an advice?